# Is it possible to rename a table in Firebird?

Tags: sql, firebird

Is it possible to rename a table in Firebird or I should create a new table and then move the data using insert?

Comment: See http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq363/

Comment: See also: http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-2486

Answer (score 9):

Apparently not.

You must either create a new table, copying over old values or create a view with the intended name which is identical to the original table.

See http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq363/ for further details.

Answer (score -7):

It is possible to change the column name by:

```
ALTER TABLE "tableName" ALTER "columnName" TO "NewColumnName";
```

Comment: For me it works in Firebird Firebird 3.0!